# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 69: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, macos

I am not a programmer but an user. I am using a software written in python for bioinformatic analysis. I have a MAC and python 2.7.11. When I run a specific command the following error appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/predict_metagenomes.py", line 375, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/predict_metagenomes.py", line 286, in main
    opts.format_tab_delimited,"metagenome prediction",verbose=opts.verbose)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/predict_metagenomes.py", line 358, in write_metagenome_to_file
    write_biom_table(predicted_metagenome, output_fp, format_fs=format_fs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/picrust/util.py", line 318, in write_biom_table
    format_fs=format_fs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/biom/table.py", line 3605, in to_hdf5
    self.group_metadata(axis='observation'), 'csr', compression)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/biom/table.py", line 3557, in axis_dump
    data=[i.encode('utf8') for i in ids],
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 69: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have read several topics about this error but I do not understand how to resolve it.

Comment: Please post your code for context.

Comment: Do you have the source code? Do you know for sure that the soft does not have any bug? Does the soft work fine on another machine? Besides, what actions lead to the error? It looks like the program received a string at some point, that was not well-formed. It *might* be a bad user input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe the problem is the input file as you said.

Answer (score 0):

`i.encode('utf8')` raises UnicodeDecodeError because `i` is a non-ascii str. To encode it (i.e. convert from unicode to str) Python first tried to decode it (i.e. convert from str to unicode) and failed (`i` is non-ascii).

To solve that pass unicode as input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try your suggestion